# Cannot publish app on UWP store due to Webview2 DLLs (store certification fail)

Tags: uwp, publishing, webview2, wack

I am still having this issue with publishing UWP.
I have:

```
Microsoft.UI.XAML - 2.8.0-prerelease.220118001,
Microsoft.Web.WebView2 - 1.0.1150.38
Target version Windows 11 (10.0; Build 22000)
```

I tried to build it it with azure build agent image windows-2022 as " pool: vmImage: 'windows-2022"
I also tried build locally with latest Win SDK and with Windows App Certification Kit 10.0.22000.194

It all builds successfully but when I try to publish it to MS partner centre then I get error on partner center:

> `API _CxxThrowException in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this
> application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this API.
>
> API __C_specific_handler in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this
> application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this API.
>
> API __std_exception_copy in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this
> application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this API.
>
> API __std_exception_destroy in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for
> this application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this API.
>
> API __std_terminate in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this
> application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this API.
>
> API __std_type_info_destroy_list in vcruntime140.dll is not supported
> for this application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this
> API.
>
> API _purecall in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this
> application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this API.
>
> API memcpy in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application
> type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this API.
>
> API memmove in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application
> type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this API.
>
> API memset in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application
> type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this API.
>
> API wcsrchr in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application
> type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this API.
>
> API ?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPEBD@Z in msvcp140.dll is not supported
> for this application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this
> API.
>
> API ?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPEBD@Z in msvcp140.dll is not supported
> for this application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this
> API.
>
> API ?__ExceptionPtrAssign@@YAXPEAXPEBX@Z in msvcp140.dll is not
> supported for this application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll
> calls this API.
>
> API ?__ExceptionPtrCopy@@YAXPEAXPEBX@Z in msvcp140.dll is not
> supported for this application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll
> calls this API.
>
> API ?__ExceptionPtrCopyException@@YAXPEAXPEBX1@Z in msvcp140.dll is
> not supported for this application type.
> Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this API.
>
> API ?__ExceptionPtrCreate@@YAXPEAX@Z in msvcp140.dll is not supported
> for this application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this
> API.
>
> API ?__ExceptionPtrCurrentException@@YAXPEAX@Z in msvcp140.dll is not
> supported for this application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll
> calls this API.
>
> API ?__ExceptionPtrDestroy@@YAXPEAX@Z in msvcp140.dll is not supported
> for this application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this
> API.
>
> API ?__ExceptionPtrRethrow@@YAXPEBX@Z in msvcp140.dll is not supported
> for this application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this
> API.
>
> API __CxxFrameHandler4 in vcruntime140_1.dll is not supported for this
> application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this API.`

Can someone help me what can I try to do next?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? Curious.

Comment: Not yet, I just used old WebView